# put 0 in a next excel column if previous 4 are empty using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I am trying to make a vb macro that determins are there 4 empty cells in a row if so it should put 0 in a next row otherwais 1 Here is what I 've done so far

```
Sub QuickCull()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("a").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("b").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("d").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Dim col As Range
Set col = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("E2", col).Resize(, 4)
  r.Select
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In r
If cell.Value = "" Then
cell.Value = 0
Else
cell.Value = 1
End If

  Next cell

End Sub
```

This way I put 0 instad of one blank row I thought about making another cell with a sum of those rows, but is where a way to do it more queckly and productivly?

Comment: please add "before" and "after" sheet screenshots. and what's wrong (if it is) with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like the following, obviously replace "WORKSHEETNAME" with the name of the worksheet:

```
Dim r as Range, cell as Range, eRow  as Long

eRow = Sheets("WORKSHEETNAME").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Sheets("WORKSHEETNAME").Range("E2:E" & eRow)

For each cell in r.cells
    If cell.Offset(0,-4).Value = "" _
    And cell.Offset(0,-3).Value = "" _
    And cell.Offset(0,-2).Value = "" _
    And cell.Offset(0,-1).Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = 0
    Else
        cell.Value = 1
    End if
Next cell
```